# Why wasn't the possible exact duplicate of a question listed on closure of the question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248721/what-is-the-current-convention-on-using-the-this-keyword-in-c) was rightly closed soon enough (before I could even cast my vote) - but upon refreshing to see it had in fact been closed, there was no link to the question specified as the original.

I refreshed, hard-refreshed, noticed comments emerging from other concerned parties then headed here. Refreshing again before typing out my question, the link suddenly pops up.

Usually the links can be seen immediately (at least that's been my perception), so I was wondering, why was there a delay in exposing the duplicate when the question was closed for that reason?

I could speculate that perhaps human-intervention, or some algorithm needs to determine the "closer duplicate" if many are specified, but presumptions can be silly.

EDIT:

Looking at the revision history it can be seen that an the question was edited *after* the closure and the alterations by Community - so, I guess the question is (forgetting the scarce possibility that this user purposefully edited out Community's input), how could the Community close-edit changes be overwritten by a user already in there editing?

Comment: The history shows that Community added it immediately after closure, yet somehow SwDevMan81's edit went through.  Weird caching issue?

Comment: Just noticed, perhaps his edit was _more substantial?_ Community edits should'nt be overwritten so easily.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the Community edit *contains* his edit; his edit is shown as empty on [the revision page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7248721/revisions).  This is definitely a good catch, and I would call it a bug.

Comment: I agree @Matthew.  It looks odd in the revision history.  It may not be a bug, but I added the tag.  Sometimes those revision history pages are weird.

Comment: If you click `Source` on SwDevMans Edit, you'll find that the Duplicate-Link is still in place in his revision.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to new feature of "merging" edits made in the same time.. though from the revision history I'm not so sure as  SwDevMan81 edit also contained the duplicate link.

Other idea is that maybe SwDevMan81 edited again during the "grace period" of 5 minutes, thus it's not visible in the revision history.

Something weird, might be related: Community revision which added the duplicate link also appears to **remove some code** from the question.... something weird is going on here:
[image: weird edit]